# scrcpy is not working showing ERROR: "adb push" returned with value 1

Tags: command-line, android, kill, mirrors, adb

I install scrcpy and

```
sudo snap install scrcpy
```

*https://snapcraft.io/scrcpy*

at first it was working fine.after a certain time it throws this error

ERROR: "adb push" returned with value 1

[image]

Comment: What does this mean? A min an hour a day? after a certain time it throws this error Please no pictures of text include the text in the question.